# while cloning update certain field dynamically

Tags: apex, trigger, field-mapping

I want to update certain field while cloning certain records,please go through the comments in coding section

```
public class ForeignFilingWizardController {
    public List<String> lstFilingType{get;set;}
    public List<String> lst_RO{get;set;}
    public List<String> lst_ISA{get;set;}
    public List<String> lst_Agent{get;set;}
    public List<String> lst_FilingAgent{get;set;}

    public string serializedFilingTypelist {get;private set;}
    public string serializedCountrylist {get;private set;}
    public string InventionDiscId {get;set;}

    public ForeignFilingWizardController() {          

         InventionDiscId  = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ParentPatentId'); 

        if (Schema.sObjectType.Patent__c.fields.Application_Filing_Type__c.isAccessible()){
            lstFilingType =  new List<string>();
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult MetaData_FilingType = Patent__c.Application_Filing_Type__c.getDescribe();        
            List<Schema.PicklistEntry> PicklistEntryFilingType = MetaData_FilingType.getPicklistValues();
            if(PicklistEntryFilingType.size() > 0){ 
                for( Schema.PicklistEntry f : PicklistEntryFilingType)
                {
                    lstFilingType.add(f.getValue());
                }            
            } 
            // serializedFilingTypelist =  JSON.serializePretty(lstFilingType);
        }

        if (Schema.sObjectType.Country__c.isAccessible()){           
            //List<Country__c> lst_RO_Country = [SELECT Country_Code__c,Name FROM Country__c where IS_RO__c = true]; 
            List<Country__c> lst_RO_Country = [SELECT Country_Code__c,Name FROM Country__c ];             
            if(lst_RO_Country.size() > 0){
                lst_RO = new List<String>();
                for(Country__c objCountry : lst_RO_Country ){            
                    lst_RO.add(objCountry.Name);              //map this value down
                }                  
            }

            //List<Country__c> lst_ISA_Country = [SELECT Country_Code__c,Name FROM Country__c where IS_ISA__c = true]; 
            List<Country__c> lst_ISA_Country = [SELECT Country_Code__c,Name FROM Country__c]; 
            if(lst_ISA_Country.size() > 0){
                lst_ISA = new List<String>();
                for(Country__c objCountry : lst_RO_Country ){            
                    lst_ISA.add(objCountry.Name);               //map this value down
                }                  
            }  

        } 

        if (Schema.sObjectType.FilingAgent__c.isAccessible()){           
            //List<Country__c> lst_RO_Country = [SELECT Country_Code__c,Name FROM Country__c where IS_RO__c = true]; 
            List<FilingAgent__c> lst_PCT_FilingAgent = [SELECT Name FROM FilingAgent__c ];             
            if(lst_PCT_FilingAgent.size() > 0){
                lst_FilingAgent = new List<String>();
                for(FilingAgent__c objFilingAgent : lst_PCT_FilingAgent ){            
                    lst_FilingAgent.add(objFilingAgent.Name);         //map this value down
                }                  
            }

            //List<Country__c> lst_ISA_Country = [SELECT Country_Code__c,Name FROM Country__c where IS_ISA__c = true]; 

        }

    }


    public class PCT_lineItem {
        String RO;//Country Code - Not the name
        String ISA;
        String Agent;
        String Entity_Type;
        Integer No_Of_Pages;
    }

    //velu
    @RemoteAction
    Public static string createnonpct(){
    List<string> lst_RO = new List<String>();
     String currentRecordId; 
       currentRecordId  = ApexPages.CurrentPage().getparameters().get('id');
         List<Patent__c> ListAssetToInsert = New List<Patent__c>();                 
        for(Patent__c pat : [select id,Title_of_Invention__c from Patent__c where id=:currentRecordId ])
            {
                    Patent__c objAsset = pat.clone();
                    objAsset.Application_Filing_Type__c ='PCT Filing';

                    objAsset.Country__c = lst_RO.Country_c;     //how to map that lst_RO value here,throwing variable lst_RO does not exit
                    objAsset.Country_Code__c = lst_ISA.Country_Code__c; //how to map that lst_ISA value here,throwing variable lst_ISA does not exit
                    objAsset.FilingAgent__c=lst_FilingAgent.FilingAgent__c; //how to map that lst_FilingAgent value here,throwing variable lst_FilingAgent does not exit

                    ListAssetToInsert.add(objAsset);

            }         

            insert ListAssetToInsert;

       return currentRecordId;


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Right off the bat, I see two things wrong with your code as-is.

1. `lst_RO`, `lst_ISA`, and `lst_FilingAgent` are class *instance* variables, and you're trying to access them in a *static* method
2. These variables are of type `List<String>`. `lst_RO.Country_Code__c` doesn't work because collections themselves don't have fields like `Country_Code__c`, and if you want to get at a specific value inside a list, you need to index into the list like `lstRO[0]`

It looks like the code that populates those 3 lists doesn't depend on anything you're getting from a user, so I'd say they (along with the code that populates them) are candidates to be made static. Doing so will grant you the ability to access those variables in your `static string createnonpct()` method.

That said, you'll still need to fix issue #2. I can't figure out what you're trying to do when you assign `Country__c`, `Country_Code__c`, and `FilingAgent__c`. Given the lists that you are generating, you ostensibly have *some* method of determining which value you want to use...but with the code and explanation that you've given so far, this is all the help I can provide.